# Real analysis, sequences and inequalities

Tags: real-analysis

Let $(x_n)$ be a sequence such that

$$ \lim x_n = \alpha $$

What would this limit be:

$$ \lim \frac{ x_1 + ... + x_n }{n} = $$

??

I feel like the limit is again $\alpha $, but I don't know how to prove it. Perhaps, we can use the $AM-GM$ inequality?

Comment: Look up the theorem/lemma of Cesaro-Stolz. Has nothing to do with means inequalities.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. Your second limit is known as the [Cesàro mean](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ces%C3%A0ro_mean) of the original sequence. If the $a_i$s converge, then the Cesàro mean converges to the same limit.

However, the converse does not hold: There are sequences whose Cesàro mean converges but the original sequence does, such as $0,1,0,1,0,\ldots$.

There's a proof [here](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Ces%C3%A0ro_Mean) or [here](http://www.ee.columbia.edu/~vittorio/CesaroMeans.pdf).